# KDE telepathy releases 0.2

Tags: ppa, kubuntu, kde, telepathy

I'm currently using the KDE telepathy PPA thats newly updated to telepathy-kde-0.2 and I'm running into a serios blocker which won't let me log into any of my accounts.

On using the Account Manager it just displays the message:
- "There was a problem while trying to connect ********@gmail.com- #(or any other account for that matter)# Some of the IM components are not working correctly (and your system does not tell us which one).

I would like to know if this is persistent for others as well or is it something with my conf, note i've been using the PPA since conception.

Thanks in advance

Image attached to show problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you need to create the directory .cache/dconf which isn't created.